# Javascript sort a specific character in a list

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am new in JavaScript and I hope you can help me.
I have a list in HTML with a select option. I would like to sort the list after the select

I would like to sort the "Z" in the select options first and the "B" as the next.
Line 1:Z
Line 2:Z
Line 3:B
....
The name of the selected option is dynamic. Is there any way how can I sort the select option after the character Z?

```html
<ul id="pi" class="list" data-enhance="false">
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle">
    <div class="tt_wrapper tooltipstered">
      <select
        data-mini="false"
        data-native-menu="true"
        name="p_01"
        id=""
        class=""
        disabled=""
      >
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Z">Z</option>
        <option value="B" selected="selected">B</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle">
    <div class="tt_wrapper tooltipstered">
      <select
        data-mini="false"
        data-native-menu="true"
        name="p_02"
        id=""
        class=""
        disabled=""
      >
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Z" selected="selected">Z</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Please fix and add relevant script

Answer (score 0):

Just `sort` the li elements on the basis of `selected` value of "`select`" element.

```js
var newLi = $("li").sort(function(ctrl1, ctrl2) {
  var returnVal = $(ctrl2).find("select").val().localeCompare($(ctrl1).find("select").val());
  return returnVal;
});

$("#pi").empty().append(newLi);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="pi" class="list" data-enhance="false">
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle">
    <div class="tt_wrapper tooltipstered">
      <select data-mini="false" data-native-menu="true" name="p_01" id="" class="" disabled="">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Z">Z</option>
        <option value="B" selected="selected">B</option>
      </select>

    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle">
    <div class="tt_wrapper tooltipstered">
      <select data-mini="false" data-native-menu="true" name="p_02" id="" class="" disabled="">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Z" selected="selected">Z</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle">
    <div class="tt_wrapper tooltipstered">
      <select data-mini="false" data-native-menu="true" name="p_02" id="" class="" disabled="">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="X" selected="selected">X</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```